# My Github contributions are gone after restoring repository

Tags: github

My Github contributions were showing correctly but

1. Somebody deleted the repository I was contributing
2. My contributions disappeared, which is ok
3. The repo was restored but my contributions never appeared again in my Github profile

I have all the settings I need for my contributions to appear and if I commit now they will show up, but how can I restore that contributions and make them appear in my profile?

[image: github contributions]

Comment: i had problems with this and the support center told me that it takes some days to update "past contributions" in certain case... idk if your fits in those category...

Comment: @Berto99 it was restored a few days ago. Maybe I need to wait a few more, not sure. Thank you!

Comment: no problem, you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue contact [Github support](https://support.github.com/contact%20,%20open%20a), open a ticket explaining what happened and they will restore your contributions.

[image: contributions graph]